# List of all element which have rel property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have different types of tag which have "rel" property using jQuery or javascript.

```
<a rel="popup10">test</a>

<div>text2</div>  

<p rel="popup20">text3</p>

<span rel="other">test4</span>
```

I want list of all element which have rel property with value like "popup", ignore number 10 or 20 whatever. i don't want span tag because it has rel property but value is not popup.

Comment: See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: `$('[rel^="popup"]')`

Comment: @u_mulder solution is perfect... [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Av5xM/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [attributes selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors). You can select all element as your requirement like this:

```
$('*[rel^="popup"]')
```

try like this:

```
$('*[rel^="popup"]').each(function(){
      alert($(this).text());
      //do what ever you want
    })
```

<kbd>[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/102/)</kbd>

Comment: it is the foreach in a list. i just show the OP the selector.

Comment: you edited your answer dude... and again - it just tests if the attribute REL begins/contains the string "popup" not if it's existent only.

Comment: @TheHe I don't think there's anything inherently wrong with the answer. Stop trying to pick bones in an egg. If OP wants a different criteria that "popup" he would've mentioned it in his question.

Comment: deleted my question already - sorry.. i TOTALLY have overread that!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following, example I want all the div have ID only, then

```
<div id='test1'>aaaa</div>
<div id='test2'>bbbb</div>
<div id='test3'>cccc</div>

<div>No ID!</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div[id]").each(function () {
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

Please see the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62KrL/)